# Another beauty hidden in a simple triangle (3)

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-transformation

In an arbitrary triangle $ABC$ pick arbitrary points $D\in BC$ and $E\in AC$ such that $DE \nparallel AB$. Denote midpoint of segment $BD$ with $F$ and midpoint of segment $AE$ with $G$.

Now draw circumscribed circles of triangles $ABC$, $FGC$ and $DEC$. Prove that all circles intersect at some point $H\ne C$

I have tried to work with circle centers. If I were able to prove that centers of all three circles lie on the same line, the rest of the proof would be trivial. However, after several unsuccessful attempts I decided to post this problem here.

[image]

Comment: This also works if you merely assume $$\frac{|AG|}{|GE|}=\frac{|BF|}{|FD|}$$

Comment: Yes! The 1/2 is a red herring. Let $I$ be the intersection of $AB$ and $ED$ after making both longer. Than for *any* line $m$ through $I$ we can draw the circle through $C$ and the two points where $m$ intersects $AC$ and $BC$ (or the longer versions of them) and ALL these circles pass through $H$. Of course this is completely crazy and even more bizarre than what you already wrote, so this comment may not be super helpful. But I like it.

Comment: Ehm, to clarify: by 'it' I mean this crazy geometrical fact which I didn't know about before you posted the question, not my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be the intersection of $c(ABC)$ and $c(GFC)$. We will show that $H$ belongs to $c(EDC)$, for it suffices to prove $\angle EHD=\angle C$.

Note that $\triangle HBF\sim \triangle HAG$: $\angle HBC=\angle HAC$ as inscribed angles over $HC$ in $c(ABC)$, and $\angle BHF=\angle BHA-\angle FHA=\angle C-\angle FHA$ and also $\angle AHG=\angle FHG-\angle FHA=\angle C-\angle FHA$, where we again used inscribed angles in $c(ABC)$ and $c(GFC)$.

$\triangle HBF\sim \triangle HAG$ together with the fact that $G$ and $F$ are midpoints of $AE$ and $BD$ imply $\triangle HBD\sim \triangle HAE$. So $\angle EHA=\angle DHB$, which implies $\angle EHG=\angle DHF$, so $\angle EHD= \angle EHF-\angle DHF= \angle EHF-\angle EHG= \angle GHF=\angle C$.

Hopefully I didn't make typos in these angles.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm missing something.

Let circles $(CDE)$ and $(CFG)$ meet second time at $H_1$, then spiral similarity with center at $H_1$ takes $E\mapsto D$ and $G\mapsto F$, so $k_1={DF\over EG}$ and rotational angle is $$\angle DH_1E = \angle DCE =: \gamma$$

Let circles $(CDE)$ and $(ABC)$ meet second time at $H_2$, then spiral similarity with center at $H_2$ takes $E\mapsto D$ and $A\mapsto B$, so $$k_2={BD \over AE}={2DF\over 2EG}=k_1$$ and rotational angle is $$\angle DH_2E = \angle DCE = \gamma$$

So this two spiral simmetry are the same, so $H_1=H_2=H$.